# Link to specific time in a youtube video via seekTo();

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, jsapi

I’m trying to get something like an index page of a youtube video so that there are links to specific times of the video.
I tried it to do like explained in [Links to Specific Times in YouTube iframe embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133079/links-to-specific-times-in-youtube-iframe-embed), but somehow it doesnt seem to work.
This is my code:

```
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', { events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady}});
    }

    function playerSeekTo(seconds) {
        player.seekTo(seconds);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video">
</iframe>

<a href="#" onclick="playerSeekTo(70); return false;">Link to 1 minutes 10 seconds</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playerSeekTo(90); return false;">Link to 1 minutes 30seconds</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playerSeekTo(110); return false;">Link to 1 minutes 50 seconds</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered three problems:

### 1st

```
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
```

led to an error. Should be

```
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
```

### 2nd

```
player = new YT.Player('video', { events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady}});
```

Obviously, `onPlayerReady` is not defined. When you remove this part, it'll work fine. What do you want to achieve with this?

```
player = new YT.Player('video');
```

### (3rd)

To me, the video you embed is not available. When I embed another video (e.g. Im69kzhpR3I), everything behaves as it should.